# Dynamic Filereference Load() of XML Files and add to XMListCollection

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

Hi im stuck on a problem in as3 i want to load a few xml files in filereference in a loop. My Idea was to Load them into the xml variable and add them to the XmllistCollection and that so on, but the xml variable gets overwritten and so only 1 xml is in my XmllistCollection.

Edit:

my New Code:

```
    public var daten:FileReferenceList;
    public var file:FileReference;
    public var xml:XML;
    private var xml_list:XMLListCollection;

public function reading(event:MouseEvent):void{
            daten=new FileReferenceList();
            var filter:FileFilter = new FileFilter("XML Dateien", "*.xml");
            daten.browse([filter]);

            daten.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, selectDaten);
        }


        private function selectDaten(event:Event):void{

            for(var i:Number = 0; i < daten.fileList.length; i++) {
                file = daten.fileList[i];
                file.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,datenLoaded);
                file.load();

            }

        }


        public function datenLoaded(event:Event):void{
        xml_list=new XMLListCollection();
        xml_list.addItem(new XML(event.target.data));
        gui.list.dataProvider=(xmllist.getallitem.nodes);
        }

        public function click(event:MouseEvent):void{

        trace(xml_list.getItemAt(0));



        }
```

I tried it your way but still when I trace(xml_list.length) i tells me 1. If I select many Objects in my Filereferncelist he only loads the first item selected and item gets added to xml_list. Btw. on the list of the dataprovider i only want to see the first node(xml.name for example) but should i get them out of an xmllistcollection the only way i think is with a loop.

ah ok it works, but how I get the xml.name from the loaded xmls in the list object ( dataprovider)? for example loading 2 xmls in xml_list

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xml>
<maindata>
    <name>murph.mp3</name>
</maindata>
<files>
    <filepart>
        <value x="20" y="15">
            <element>155</element>
        </value>
    </filepart>
</files>
</xml>
```

I want to make my List element look like this way but dont know how to realize and didnt found any examples in web on top should stay the name xml_list.maindata.name and on bottom an operation for easy example here(1+1) or (@value x+ @value y)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hyzzb.jpg

Comment: Sry I just made a new Post to keeped the overview of the Thread                          Its a Question

Comment: You should remove this line : `xml_list=new XMLListCollection();`.

Comment: but i have to create an object of XMLListCollection()?

Comment: You can simply write : `private var xml_list:XMLListCollection = new XMLListCollection();`

Comment: ah ok it works, but how I get the xml.name from the loaded xmls in the list object ( dataprovider)?

Comment: Could you put an example of your XML data and what you to extract form it ?

Comment: I edited my answer, take a look.

Comment: ah ok thanks but how can i avoid he adds the same element again if its already in the array i would think with a kind of member method

Comment: I edited my answer, take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake in your code is that you are initializing ( overwriting ) every time your `XMLListCollection`, so of course at the end you will get only the last added item, so your code can be like this :

```
function datenLoaded(event:Event):void
{               
    xml_list.addItem(XML(event.target.data));

    // to get an XML element ( test.name ) :
    xml_list.addItem(XML(event.target.data).name);

    // here your don't need an ArrayList
    // you can use the XMLListCollection as a data provider for the list
    list.dataProvider = xml_list;
}
```

**EDIT :**

To verify if you'v already added the name or not, you can, for example, use an `Object` where you store your names to verify the new ones :

```
private var names:Object = {};
```

Then your function can be like this :

```
function datenLoaded(event:Event):void 
{
    var xml:XML = XML(event.target.data);
    var name:String = xml.maindata.name;

    // if we don't have already added this name, so add it
    if(!names[name]){
        names[name] = name;
        xml_list.addItem(XML(event.target.data).maindata.name);
    }               
    list.dataProvider = xml_list;
}
```

Hope that can help.

Comment: thank u very much for all that answears but I think that wasnt my last question for the moment I can continue program :P

Comment: Anybody knows how i can add 2 Elemnts to Dataprovider?

Comment: @Mralladin What do you mean by "add 2 elements to dataprovider" ?

Comment: watch in my first thread i made an example with paint the regular list looks like http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WSc2368ca491e3ff923c946c5112135c8ee9e-7fff.html 
but i want to add under the list element another element
like this here http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf651fa-7fff.html  
first example but instead of a hyperlink i want there a value, on the picture it should be clearer to understand :)